# Find the value of x in log

Tags: logarithms

If $\log_{\sqrt 8} \,⁡x=\frac {10}3$, then find the value of $x$.
I get the intermediate step of $2 ^ {10/9}$ but in the answers it says $2^5$. How?

Comment: How did you get $2^{10/9}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\log_{\sqrt8}x &=& \dfrac{10}3 \\
x &=& \sqrt{8}^{10/3} \\
x &=& (\sqrt{2^3})^{10/3} \\
x &=& (2^{3/2})^{10/3} \\
x &=& 2^5 \\
\end{array}$$